# Why doesn't the total number of features from data.shape agree with those that are shown during recursive feature elimination?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rfe

Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, I'm a relative newby to both Python and ML (and a new poster here, the trifecta of ignorance). Anyway, `data.shape` is telling me that me dataset is `(150,177)`, however there are only 175 "False" or "True"  selected features, and also 175 feature rankings produced by this RFE code (see below). I understand that 1 of the 177 is my output, but the 176 input features still doesn't match up with 175 from the `Selected Features` or `Feature Ranking` output. What am I missing??

```
#load Discovery Metabolomics dataset
from numpy import set_printoptions
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from pandas import read_csv
#load data
filename="DiscoveryMetabolomics_data.csv"
data=read_csv(filename)
array=data.values
Y=array[:, 0]
X=array[:, 1:-1]
#feature selection
model=LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
rfe=RFE(model, 5)
fit=rfe.fit(X,Y)
#Summarize Scores
set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(data.shape)
print("Num Features: %d" %fit.n_features_)
print("Selected Features: %s" %fit.support_)
print("Feature Ranking %s" %fit.ranking_)
```

`(150, 177)`
Num Features: `5`

Selected Features:
`[False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False  True False False False False False False False False False False False  True False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False  True False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False  True False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False  True False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False]`

Feature Ranking
`[157 171  40 167 114 143  35 168   7 142  29 162 158 100  95  91 159 160 45  69 118 116  36 151 132 163   1  74  12 127  10  16  58 128 122  79 59   9   1  72 149  42   5  60 119  27  41 138  25 101 156   2  88  43 44  55   6  11 153  17 104   3 166 146  32 141  94 155 145  93  19 130 13  78 139  68   8 123  64 102  67  30  52   1 137  38  61  49 109 140 57  90  26 148 103  63 144 105  21  53 136  31  47  37  86  65 110  28 85 111  14  80 147  98 161  82  22  48  89  96  92 133  76 170  71  33 99  34 112  46 115  18  50 107 126 150 129  51  66  56   1  97  20  84 131  87  73  83 125  39 108  24  62 121  70  75 120 106   1 134  54 165 15 152 169 154  77 135  81 117 124   4  23 164 113]`

Comment: Since you're new, please learn how to make a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for future questions. In you case, nobody can reproduce the behavior if they don't have the input data. But that is irrelevant, just feed some dummy values. In the process of creating the minimal example you may very well have found the issue...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I assumed it was something wrong with my code (as you pointed out below) since there was a mismatch with the data shape and RFE output. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```py
array = np.zeros((150, 177))

print(array.shape, array[:, 1:-1].shape)
# output (150, 177) (150, 175)
```

Using `[1:-1]` takes all values starting with the first and up to (exluding)  the last (index -1). So, your input has 175 dimensions, and thus, your output too.

This is simply the way indexing works in Python. If you want all elements until the end, use `[1:]`:

```py
print([1, 2, 3][1:-1])
# output [2]

print([1, 2, 3][1:])
# output [2, 3]
```